# "mit sich bringen" vs. "mit sich führen"

Tags: difference

> Dieses Verfahren **bringt/führt** allerdings auch Nachteile mit sich.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "etwas mit sich führen" und "etwas mit sich bringen"?

Comment: Alternative: "Dieses Verfahren birgt allerdings auch Nachteile."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mit sich führen* kommt hauptsächlich in behördlichen Auflagen vor:

Man hat einen Sozialversicherungsausweis, eine Aufenthaltsberechtigung oder dergleichen mit sich zu führen, im Auto vielleicht noch Warndreieck und Verbandskasten.

Bei Flüssen, Lawinen etc. wird *mit sich führen* auch verwendet, so dass sich die Bedeutung mit *einen realen Gegenstand dabei haben* umschreiben lässt.

Im übertragenen Sinn sind das keine Alternativen, da heißt es immer *mit sich bringen*.

Comment: "Bei Flüsse, Lawinen" - hier müsste es dann auch der Plural von Fluss sein, evtl. hast du nur ein "n" vergessen. ("Flüssen")